# adb for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

Does Visual Studio 2013 have something similar to adb (Android Debug Bridge) where I can see the complete debug log of my Windows Phone app?

I have issues in the javscript code of my phonegap app and since this does not raise an error to VisualStudio during debug run, I don't get any info where and why it gets stuck.

In adb I can get the whole android phone log which may contain some vague error messages that at least point me into the direction of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this nothing similar to the adb in the windows phone